# Arduino Timer Library and remaining time

Tags: c, timer, arduino

I use this timer Library : https://github.com/JChristensen/Timer/tree/v2.1

This is a very good lib , it works perfectly and is relatively simple to use. But I need to have the remaining time of a timer to display it.

I feel like I missed something .

For now , I note :
duration, departure , time Arduino and I do the math .

The best would be **to recover the remaining time of the timer** . I think it's possible, but I do not understand. Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i find the solution :

```
remaining_time = _events[id].period - (now - _events[id].lastEventTime);
```

I will fork the project to add this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the README for this library we see the basic way that this all works.

> The library does not interfere with the built-in timers, it just uses millis() in a basic type of scheduler to decide when something needs doing.

I'm not sure how much experience you have with interrupts but, it's important to note that timer interrupt can sometimes be "registered" and then they just go. This does not appear to be the case here based on the update call it seems that this library is actually just registering a callback function based on when millis() returns the required delta in time.

With that in mind my best suggestion for acquiring the remaining time is making the same calculation the library is. Basically use the library as normal but use millis() at the first use of the library and continue calling it to track the delta yourself.

The only other option I can find is in the .cpp which makes the call

```
_events[i].lastEventTime = millis();
```

However I haven't looked to find exactly how this works.

Edit:
On a more personal note I would really suggest you learn how the hardware timers work. They will make your project run smoother, be less likely to crash, and they are more like how a "real world" project would be completed if you are interested in learning that.

Comment: Thank you , I understood now